# access another model within ng-repeat

Tags: json, angularjs, model-view-controller

This seems to me like it should be painfully obvious but I've not found an example anywhere.

I have two models, sessions and users:

```
$scope.sessions = 
[{
    "sessionId":"1",
    "userId":"12345",
    "date": "17/07/2014",
    "test_name":"2014beta",
    "status": "new",
    "assigned_to":""
}]

$scope.users = 
[{
    "userId":"12345",
    "name":"Frank Tester",
    "dob": "17/07/1967",
    "eyes":"blue"
}]
```

A session belongs to a user, so in the database, the user ID is saved within the session model (over-simplified models above).

In a listing of sessions, I'd like to include the user name and other user detail, both of which are accessed via the user model.

I have both users and sessions available within the scope. I use an ng-repeat to list all sessions (and show things like `session.name`, `session.time` etc), how do I access the user name from the other model by it's ID? ie. I'd would think I should be able to access `session.user.name`

I'll need to do this in a couple of different places and will need to access different bits of cross-referenced data - Is there a simple way to do this within the template or do I need to build a service for this? A directive? A filter?

Comment: Could you just loop through `sessions` and inject a corresponding user object before hand then used it in `ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put another ng-repeat inside session ng-repeat and filter it by session.userId

please see that demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/BOITOEEYDM9tFH3zbMIW

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="session in sessions">
      {{session.date}}
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="user  in users | filter: session.userId ">
          {{user.name}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.sessions = 
[{
    "sessionId":"1",
    "userId":"12345",
    "date": "17/07/2014",
    "test_name":"2014beta",
    "status": "new",
    "assigned_to":""
}]

$scope.users = 
[{
    "userId":"12345",
    "name":"Frank Tester",
    "dob": "17/07/1967",
    "eyes":"blue"
}]
});
```

Comment: That seems all too easy (but definitely works - thanks @sylwester!). How does this solution rate so far as performance goes though? Once I have a thousand users and sessions, does this mean it would loop though every user per session or is the filtering method efficient enough for this?

Comment: You have to try that, but that depends of end client hardware performance. Just do you really want to put a thousand users on page ?

Comment: That's a good point - probably not. I think I may have to make the request to the server in this instance provide me with a mix of models - sessions + session users all in one. thanks.